# Combine images as frames to make a video with Python

Tags: python, video, mpeg

I'm looking for a Python library that can combine images into a video.

A library that just allows you to create an empty video and feed images into it as frames is ideal.

Preferably with support for MPEG compression of the video file as well.

Comment: Were you able to do this?

Comment: I wasn't. Some people I spoke did it with Matlab, though. It surprised me that Matlab could do this fairly easily while Python could not at all.

Comment: Oh okay. I'll look into matlab then.

Answer (score 2):

If you run linux then you can use ffmpeg to do this from the command line there is a python wrapper called [pyFFmpeg](https://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/) that you can use - there is also [pymedia](http://pymedia.org/) but it doesn't look to be maintained.

BTW there are a number of projects that provide builds of ffmpeg for windows.

Answer (score 1):

gstreamer is the tool you are looking for. you'll probably need an appsrc or something like that.